# Erro ao usar glyphicon com bootstrap-sass

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, sass, bootstrap-glyphicons

Boa tarde, estou tentando trabalhar com `bootstrap-sass` e `sass`, porém, ao incluir um ícone na minha class, nada acontece. Logo abaixo segue a linha de código que representa a mesma, gostaria de saber se devo configurar alguma coisa a mais para poder usar as fontes do bs ou se estou fazendo algo de errado.

Obs.: Não sei se vem ao caso mas para o backend estou usando django 1.9.

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-sprockets.scss";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";


.tablestyle{
    @extend .col-md-6, .col-md-offset-2;
    .table{
        @extend .table, .table-striped;
        .info{
            @extend .btn, .btn-info, .btn-xs;
        }
        .edit{
            @extend .glyphicon, .glyphicon-edit;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Se você usar somente a class do glyph, ele funciona? Diretamente a glyph class no html.

Comment: O Bootstrap já importa os glyphicons, então, você não precisa importar novamente, é só usar diretamente `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit></span>"`. Outra coisa é que no Bootstrap você referencia o glyphicon por `glyphicon glyphicon-user`, exemplo. Você não precisa do `.scss` nos seus `@import`. Veja isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369036/bootstrap-3-glyphicons-are-not-working

Comment: @CelsomTrindade já tentei isso e não funciona também.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida utilizei o que estava na question que tu me indicou, sobrescrevi o caminho do font-face e funcionou. obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado!

Comment: Posta a sua solução e marca como resposta, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema utilizando como base um comentário logo acima, apenas sobrescrevi o caminho do font face, então ele ficou assim:

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-sprockets.scss";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";

// font face
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../vendor/bootstrap/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../vendor/bootstrap/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded- opentype'), url('../vendor/bootstrap/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../vendor/bootstrap/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../vendor/bootstrap/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```